# javascript dynamically add frame to frameset

Tags: javascript, iframe, variables, external, frame

The following favelet in IE is causing something similar to a document.write which is displaying [object]?

I am attempting to dynamically add a frame to get javascript variables from another page to autopopulate a form. I cannot edit the source this must execute from a favorite or bookmark.

```
javascript:
var newFrame = document.createElement("frame");
newFrame.id = "externalFrame";    
newFrame.name = "externalFrame"; 
newFrame.src = "listparent.jsp?listType=all";
var m = document.getElementById('mainframeset');
m.appendChild(newFrame);
```

The html page looks like this

```
<html>
   <frameset id=mainframeset cols="*,0">
      <frame src="issue.jsp" name="editor"> 
      <frame  src="adminPoller.jsp" name="poller" scrolling=no>
   </frameset> 
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Frameset is really ugly way to do websites, why can't you do it properly, with iframes?

Comment: properly with iframes? why not ajax?

Comment: I also tempted doing this as an added iframe. Same result occured.

Answer (score 1):

I finally ended up solving my problem by adding an element to a frame document instead of the mainframeset.

```
var body = window.frames['editor'].document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var elem = window.frames['editor'].document.createElement("iframe");
body.appendChild(elem);
```